# Error while building Jar file in Intellij | Maven Plugins are missing?

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I am getting below error while building Jar file. I am stuck with this issue from so long please advice.

```
Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.5.6:compile (default) on project Clinical_CDF: Execution default of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.5.6:compile failed: Compilation failed
```

below is my pom.xml, I am trying to clone my git branch in intellij, after that trying to create a code but before that I am not even able to resolve dependencies . below is the content/xml code from pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.optum.csgbdptenant.clinical.cdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>Clinical_CDF</artifactId>
    <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11.8</scala.binary.version>
        <spark.version>2.4.4.0-mapr-630</spark.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mapr-releases</id>
            <url>http://repository.mapr.com/maven/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4.1-mapr-630</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4.1-mapr-630</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
            <artifactId>lift-json_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>2.4.4.0-mapr-630</version>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0-mapr-1803-r1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>3.0.1</version>-->
        <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalactic</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalactic_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.nscala-time/nscala-time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.nscala-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>nscala-time_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mapr.db</groupId>
            <artifactId>maprdb-spark</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-mapr-1710</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>hbase</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>1.1.13.0-mapr-630</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>hive-hbase-handler</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>2.3.6-mapr-1912</version>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>json4s-native_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0-M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hortonworks/shc-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8-mapr-1904</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1-mapr-1408</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.optum.csgbdptenant.Common</groupId>
            <artifactId>Common</artifactId>
            <version>6.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/jars/Common-6.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>PBEEncryption_Optum</groupId>
            <artifactId>PBEEncryption_Optum</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/jars/PBEEncryption_Optum.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>



        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>scripts/src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>scripts/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testSourceDirectory>scripts/src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>Acquire</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*TESTS*.*</include>
                    </includes>

                </configuration>

                <!--<configuration>-->
                <!--<skipTests>false</skipTests>-->
                <!--</configuration>-->

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

adding the log also

```
 [INFO] 
[INFO] ----------< com.optum.csgbdptenant.clinical.cdf:Clinical_CDF >----------
[INFO] Building Clinical_CDF 4.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Clinical_CDF ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\sbhatt56\IdeaProjects\CASE_DETAIL_FACT\scripts\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Clinical_CDF ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:4.5.6:compile (default) @ Clinical_CDF ---
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.11.8
[WARNING]  net.liftweb:lift-json_2.11:3.4.1 requires scala version: 2.11.12
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] Using incremental compilation using Mixed compile order
[INFO] Compiler bridge file: C:\Users\sbhatt56\.sbt\1.0\zinc\org.scala-sbt\org.scala-sbt-compiler-bridge_2.11-1.5.8-bin_2.11.8__52.0-1.5.8_20211211T222914.jar
[INFO] compiling 14 Scala sources to C:\Users\sbhatt56\IdeaProjects\CASE_DETAIL_FACT\target\classes ...
[ERROR] C:/Users/sbhatt56/IdeaProjects/CASE_DETAIL_FACT/scripts/src/main/scala/member_policy.scala:5: expected class or object definition
[ERROR] one error found
```

Code testing

```
object RDDWithSession {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  //val sparkSession=SparkSession.builder()
  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("RRDSparkSession")
    .config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://apsrp07754.uhc.com:11848")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()

    var recordcounts = ""
    var notifymsg = ""


    val updateddate = sparkSession.sql(s"select distinct update_dt from clinical.mbr_cse_pol_ref SORT by date(update_dt) DESC LIMIT 3")
    notifymsg = s"Updated Records : $updateddate"


  }
```

Thanks for the help !!

Comment: The error is `Compilation failed`, there must be some other error before this error. Post the complete log.

Comment: hi , 
i have updated my question please have a look .

Comment: Post the code for `member_policy.scala`

Comment: updated , pls check

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)